# How do I get my coworkers to try out my wiki (DokuWiki) with its provided apache server?

Tags: web-server, ip, host, wiki

I'm restarting an attempt to make a case for a Wiki at my workplace. Our IT is very difficult to work with and unfortunately, it looks like we will have to do this somehow without installation or admin permissions until the test case is a success. Thankfully DokuWiki has a simple version (https://www.dokuwiki.org/install:dokuwiki_on_a_stick) with a provided stripped down apache webserver that still allows other people to connect to it.

It works absolutely great and fits our need, except I am the only one who can use it (since I am the host) at the moment. I'm trying to get my coworkers to connect to it and try it out for a little bit and do some minor entries.

Here is the situation:

- All of us are now working remotely at home on our work provided laptop.
- We are all using VPN (Cisco AnyConnect Secure Mobility Client) to connect.

I don't know what IP address to give to my coworkers. I typed in ipconfig in CMD and also https://www.whatsmyip.org/ but I'm not sure which one to use (IPV6? IPV4? Public?). This is internal for my fellow coworkers, I do not wish for this to be accessible by the outside public. In a similar question I asked on DokuWiki's forum months ago, someone said to use my VPN IP. Is that my IPV4 while using VPN?

Related Question: Does using VPN give you the same environment as a LAN? Will it help me out in this situation?

If anyone have other suggestions that would be great too. Thank you.

Comment: How do you connect to it? Tell your colleagues to connect to it the same way.

Comment: http://localhost:8800/, but I can substitute localhost with an IP. Just not sure which one to use.

Comment: What's the ip address of the computer it's running on? That's the ip address to use.

Comment: I typed ipconfig into CMD, which type of IP address do I use? There's a lot of different options.

Answer (score 1):

There are many ways to setup VPN environments, and the answer depends on the way the VPN environment is set up.

You need to talk to your IT department if it is possible to connect to networks that are behind VPN clients. Your IT department has the necessary information to answer your question.